# ReplaceAll method in String API

Tags: java, java-11

I have a condition where I have to replace some character(special, non-print-able and other special character) from string as mention below

```
 private static final String NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS = "[^\\x00-\\x7F]";
    private static final String ASCII_CONTROL_CHARACTERS = "[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]";
    private static final String NON_PRINTABLE_CHARACTERS = "\\p{C}";

stringValue.replaceAll(NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS, "").replaceAll(ASCII_CONTROL_CHARACTERS, "")
                .replaceAll(NON_PRINTABLE_CHARACTERS, "");
```

can we refactor above code means we can use single "replaceAll" method and put all conditions inside?

is there any way please advice.

Comment: You can separate regular expressions with `|` to do an "or".

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Could you please give an example?

Comment: You mean an example like `"re1|re2"`? Is this really such a mystery?

Comment: The way you combine the patterns, seems to contradict your goals. The definition of `ASCII_CONTROL_CHARACTERS` implies that you want to keep tabs and line breaks, but `NON_PRINTABLE_CHARACTERS` includes them, so you end up removing them. In fact, tabs and line breaks are the only non printable characters left on the third replace operation. I think, you are better off thinking first, what you actually want to keep, which is only a small deviation from your first pattern, i.e. `stringValue.replaceAll("[^\r\n\t\\x20-\\x7F]", "")` and that’s it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `Pattern` [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), it should also be possible to combine the three character class patterns into a single character class:

```
private static final String NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS = "[^\\x00-\\x7F]";
private static final String ASCII_CONTROL_CHARACTERS = "[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]";
private static final String NON_PRINTABLE_CHARACTERS = "\\p{C}";
```

becomes

```
private static final String COMBINED =
  "[[^\\x00-\\x7F][\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]\\p{C}]";
```

or

```
private static final String COMBINED =
    "[" + NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS + ASCII_CONTROL_CHARACTERS 
        + NON_PRINTABLE_CHARACTERS + "]";
```

Note that `&&` (intersection) has lower precedence than the implicit union operator so all of the `[` and `]` meta-characters in the above are required.

<sup>You decide which version you think is clearer.  It is a matter of opinion.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

You can use regex or operator `|`

```
private static final String NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS = "[^\\x00-\\x7F]";
private static final String ASCII_CONTROL_CHARACTERS = "[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]";
private static final String NON_PRINTABLE_CHARACTERS = "\\p{C}";

public static String process(String stringValue) {
    return stringValue.replaceAll(NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS + "|"+ ASCII_CONTROL_CHARACTERS +"|"+ NON_PRINTABLE_CHARACTERS, "");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String val = process("A9339a0zzz]3");
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Code point

You might consider an alternate avenue, other than using regex. You can use the [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer number for each character, and query `Character` class for the category of character.

```
String input = … ;
String output = 
    input
    .codePoints()  // Returns an `IntStream` of code point `int` values.
    .filter( codePoint -> ! Character.isISOControl( codePoint ) )  // Filter for the characters you want to keep. Those code points flunking the `Predicate` test will be omitted. 
    .filter( codePoint -> codePoint < 127 ) ;  // Within US-ASCII range. Code point 127 is US-ASCII but is DEL, so we filter that out here. 
    .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )  // Convert the `int` code point integers back into characters. 
    .toString() ;  // Make a `String` from the contents of the `StringBuilder`.
```

The [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) class has many of the classifications defined by the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium). You can use them to narrow down the stream of code points to those which represent your desired characters.